# git tower 2 keeps refreshing my view and throws the cursor to beginning of commit list every time I refocus the app

Tags: refresh, git-tower

I am on the main screen, going over commits one at a time in MASTER branch, lets say I use the keyboard arrows.

Every time I go to another app (Eclipse) and then go back to tower, the commit list gets refreshed, and I'm being brutally thrown to the top of the list. WTF.

The above also happens every once in a while without exiting and re-entering the app.

I have the latest version (2.2.0 build 274) but this amazingly annoying thing appears on older versions as well - and I don't seem to find anything on the web about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Tobias from the Tower team.

What you describe seems to be happening for a couple of other users, too. I can't give you an ETA, but we already have this on our list of things to do!

Thanks for for pointing this out!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Going to wait for the fix..
This may also help - I noticed that if the cursor is somewhere between the first and the ~90'th commit - When I refocus the app, the cursor placement is intact (although the commit list gets refreshed, and the view jumps up).
But.. when I go over the rest of commits after the ~90th commit the cursor jumps to the first commit as the view gets refreshed when the app gets refocused. Strange behaviour...